# Build error using Astro framework & react-image-gallery

Tags: reactjs, image-gallery, react-dom, astrojs, react-dom-server

I am using `"astro": "~2.3.0"` with `"@astrojs/react": "~2.1.1"` (using `"react": "~18.2.0"`, `"react-dom": "~18.2.0"`)  & `"react-image-gallery": "~1.2.11"` and when I try to build (with `astro build`) the astro app I get this error from the `ImageGallery` component:

```
 error   Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
```

and it seems like there is an error on some import

The component responsible for the error is:

```
import React from "react";
import ImageGallery from "react-image-gallery";
import "react-image-gallery/styles/scss/image-gallery.scss";
import styles from "./styles.module.scss";

function ProjectPage({ project = {} }) {
  return (
    <div className={styles.project}>
      <ImageGallery
        items={project.images}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
export default ProjectPage;
```

and I am using it on another astro file with the `client:load` directive like:

```
<ProjectView project={selectedProject} client:load />
```

The issue comes on prod build and **not** when running on dev server.
Does anybody have an idea why this happens ??

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it was a prod build error and a workaround is:

```
import Gallery from "react-image-gallery";
const ImageGallery = (Gallery as any).default ?? Gallery;
```

[Gitgub issue answer](https://github.com/xiaolin/react-image-gallery/issues/727#issuecomment-1527627275)